# Clear Autofilled Password on formload in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

i am working on a mobile web Dev project where in the login page i need to prevent or clear the password field which gets autofilled. I tried with having a dummy field with type="password" which is hidden and the other is the actual password filed. I have put the the dummy field ahead of the actual password field. I thought it would work but itsn't. Here is the snippet of my code. The below is for the dummy field

```
<ion-input style="display:none;">
   <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
   <input type="password" name="foilautofill" maxlength="25" ng-value="" ng-model="vm.user.password" autocomplete="off"/>
</ion-input>
```

This is for the actual field

```
<ion-input class="item item-input item-floating-label">
   <ion-label>Password </ion-label>
   <input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="{{'PASSWORD' | translate}}" maxlength="25" ng-model="vm.user.password" autocomplete="off">
</ion-input>
```

Comment: I'm afraid neither web browser functionality nor web programming are on-topic here. Your question would be more appropriate at [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and succeeded as follows (2-steps needed):

```
document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value='1'; //set any value
document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value=''; //set empty value
```

Autofilled value could not be just emptied, it had to be set in some other value first, then emptied.

You might want to put it in document.onload or if you have JQuery, $(document).ready..

BTW I hate it when developers break automated things on purpose.

Comment: If it is some thing very much required what can be the other alternative?

Comment: I do not understand, what do you mean? Did you try this, did it work?

Comment: You could mark this as an answer if you feel that it is the right one.

Comment: This worked for me in Chrome within my React app's 'componentDidMount()' function.

Comment: This doesn't work in some browsers like Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94, I've read this is because in some browsers the password autofill happened after the Document.onload, and in javascript there is no way to detect the autofill event made by the browser